# Loading data to Highchart from MySQL and displaying in appropriate way

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I am facing the problem with highchart. I've been looking for solution for 2 days without result.

**live-data.php**

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/json");
include("./dbSettings.php");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT current_ts, heartRate FROM data WHERE  id='1234'");
if (!$result) {
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
$ret = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $current_time = strtotime($row['current_ts'])*1000;
        $heartRate = intval($row['heartRate']);  
        $y = rand(0, 100);          
        $ret[] = array($current_time, $heartRate);     
}
    echo json_encode($ret, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

**output from live-data.php**

```
[[1463404815000,131],[1463404926000,108],[1463404927000,180],[1463404928000,160],[1463404967000,143],[1463404968000,105],[1463404969000,107],[1463404976000,100],[1463404977000,123],[1463867458000,108],[1463867459000,113],[1463867460000,108],[1463867494000,97],[1463867495000,158],[1463867496000,74]]
```

**index.html** (it's totally wrong, but I attach it)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="highcharts@*" data-semver="4.0.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/4.0.1/highcharts.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },



        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('live-data.php', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I would like to make my chart looking like this one below, but a bit more detailed. I will retrieve data from my database every minute. Chart will be updated after manually refresh, but in the future I will make it dynamically (using ajax). It will be great if I could show data in appropriate way (i.e. April 7, 2016, 15:12:38)

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/

I hope someone can help me on my way.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: I guess that you mean xAxis labels, you can edit that by [xAxis labels option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats)

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed you are talking about tooltip dates because on Axis your label will be too long.

You need to play with `dateTimeLabelFormats`. See my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/qq5rqazj/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are probably right. Can you tell how can I deal with json file putting in the same directory, as my JS. I've made a copy of https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=? and changed line for  $.getJSON('aapl-c.json', function (data) { but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should set full path, not `aapl-c.json` but `http://yourwebsite/path/to/file/aapl-c.json`

Comment: It can be a name of file, but all staff should be run on the webserver.